# c# foreach into LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have been using foreach statement and resharpen suggested that i use LINQ instead. This is what i came up with but i'm getting error. Can someone give me a hand with this:

**Question 1:**
Foreach statement:

```
List<string> captured = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    captured.Add(row["ID"].ToString());
```

attempt LINQ Statement

```
var captured2 = table.Rows.ToList().ForEach(row => { captured.Add(row["ID"].ToString());});
```

**Question 2:**

Also i got this compound statement too which i have no clue on how to create the LINQ statement

```
        List<string> captured = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                if (!col.ToString().Equals("Name") || !col.ToString().Equals("ID"))
                    captured.Add(row[col.ToString()].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: And what's the message of that error...

Comment: I would leave how it is. It looks more readable.

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question1
From my Resharper:

```
var captured = (from DataRow row in table.Rows select row["ID"].ToString()).ToList();
```

The Second Question :

```
var captured = (from DataRow row in table.Rows from DataColumn col in table.Columns where !col.ToString().Equals("Name") || !col.ToString().Equals("ID") select row[col.ToString()].ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I use ReSharper to do it for me :D

```
List<string> captured = (from DataRow row in table.Rows select row["ID"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

When Resharper suggests that you use LINQ instead, put your cursor on the squiggly and hit Alt-Enter. Resharper will fix it for you. If hotkeys don't work, you can hover over the squiggly and an icon will appear that lets you tell Resharper to fix the code.

As a matter of fact, this applies to all Resharper suggestions. I've never met a suggestion that it couldn't fix itself.

Comment: OMG i didn't know you could do that!! Great thanks a lot bud!

Comment: @civic.sir No problem bud. Please mark the answers that solved your problems. It helps StackOverflow organize its content.

Comment: I'm trying to but i have to wait atleast 10minutes before i do. But i will forsure mark yours as answered. Thanks

Comment: That's interesting. I thought OP used this feature and generated code was wrong :)

Comment: @Reniuz I can't wait for the day Resharper breaks my code and I can go "AHA! I knew it wasn't perfect!" So far, no such luck.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR Resharper can break your code though. Atleast I know two of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's what ReSharper meant.

A better Linq method would be:

```
var captured2 = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["ID"].ToString()).ToList();
```

I'm surprised it didn't translate that way for you - I've never seen ReSharper translate a `foreach` into a `.ForEach()` call.

Comment: `DataRowCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` so this won't compile without a `.Cast<DataRow>()`.

Comment: @JLRishe While you're right, I suspect OP's code also won't compile `table.Rows.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

ForEach does not return any IEnumerable.

Don't assign it to captured2 and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

You should really ask Question 2 as a separate question, but here is how you would do it:

```
var values = (from DataRow row in table.Rows
             from string col in new[] {"Name", "ID"}
             select row[col].ToString()).ToList();
```

There's no need to iterate through all the columns since you know which ones you want.

However, a far better approach would be to do this:

```
var values2 = (from DataRow row in table.Rows
               select new
               {
                   Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                   ID = row["ID"].ToString()
               }).ToList();
```